# Deciding if a graph is "Single Connected"

Tags: graphs, connected-components

The definition of "Single Connected" is that for every $u,v \in V$ there is at most a single simple path from $u$ to $v$, and at most a single simple path from $v$ to $u$.

The objective is to find an efficient algorithm to decide whether the graph is "single connected".

I've managed to come up with the following algorithm:

```
for all v in V:
      Perform DFS(v)
      for all e in E, check if:
          there is a forward edge
          there is a cross edge
```

if there is a forward edge/cross edge, we have found another simple path between $u$ and $v$, therefor the graph is not single connected.

This algorithm runs in $O(|V| \cdot (|V|+|E|))$ which is okay, but according to a colleague, this is solveable in linear time.

The most I've been able to think of is using tarjan's algorithm to reduce the graph to a DAG , however I am unsure on how to proceed from there.

I've also managed to find this question:

[is it possible to determine using a single depth-first search, in O(V+E) time, whether a directed graph is singly connected?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/86811/is-it-possible-to-determine-using-a-single-depth-first-search-in-ove-time-w)

yet it remains unanswered.

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be "exactly one path"?

Comment: What is a "simple path" for you?

Comment: The condition stated in the problem is “at most one simple path”.      the definition of simple path is as usual: no cycles, no repeating vertices/edges.

Answer (score 2):

Is your graph directed or undirected?

If your graph is undirected then the condition you mention is equivalent to your graph being a forest (every connected component is a tree).

Comment: Consider a directed graph with edges $\overrightarrow{12},\overrightarrow{13},\overrightarrow{42},\overrightarrow{43}$.  It is "single connected". Is the corresponding undirected graph a forest?

Comment: A directed cycle is not singly connected — there are two simple paths from $1$ to itself.

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning, the graph were trying to decide whether it is “single connected” is directed.